# Can I use a UIBarButtonSystemItem for a UIButton?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to customize a `UIButton` and I want to use a [`UIBarButtonSystemItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIBarButtonSystemItem) style that is available for a `UIBarButtonItem` object.

How do I use a `UIBarButtonSystemItem` style on a `UIBUtton` object?

Comment: You can find system images for any buttons by means of this extractor: https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor And use them for your buttons

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. UIBarButton and UIButton are two completely different classes. The best you can do is find images close to what you're looking for and add them to UIButtons.

Answer (score 4):

Use a UIView instead of a UIButton that contains a UIToolbar with UIBarButtonItems.

```
UIView *buttonContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 44)];
buttonContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIToolbar *dummyBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 44)];

UIBarButtonItem *b1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(doSomething:)];
UIBarButtonItem *b2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(doSomething:)];

NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:b1, b2, nil];

[dummyBar setItems:items];

[buttonContainer addSubview:dummyBar];

...

-(void)doSomething:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Button pushed");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the inheritance about UIBarButtonItem and UIButton:

UIBarButtonItem->UIBarItem->NSObject

UIButton->UIControl->UIView->UIResponder->NSObject

you can see, there is not possible to use UIBarButtonSystemItem on UIButton, UIBarButtonItem and UIButton only commonly inherited from NSObject.

Answer (score 0):

you can only use them on a toolbar on navbar.

a workaround/hack could be use UIToolbars where you want UIBarButtons to be placed