# Swift-iOS-Access iOS's default icons / images from UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, icons, identifier

In Bar Button Item, you can set the Identifier from storyboard and the button can change from text to iOS stock icons like delete, add, edit, etc.

How can I access these icons, or at least set it for my UIButtons?

Either from code or storyboard is fine for now.

Comment: It kind of does, but I want to use UIButton with iOS default icon, not UIBarButtonSystemItem. In Android they provide you stock icons so you can use it for your buttons to achieve consistent look and feel. And I see those icons in apps like Yahoo! or Facebook Messenger. If the only way to achieve that based on the other question is from 3rd parties and not from Apple that's really counter intuitive

Comment: That post is also about using UIButtons... The "icons" you mentioned are of UIBarButtonSystemItem style and that other question is about turning UIBarButtonSystemItem into UIButtons. According to the accepted solution, it can't be done: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21360626/2274694